# HTTP 401 user is unauthorized on web service call from C#, works in Postman

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, http-status-code-401, service-reference

I am trying to call a service by adding reference of it in my C# console application. It requires bearer authentication.

When I post from Postman, it works fine and returns the response. But when I access it from my C# code, it returns a http 401 error.

Postman CURL looks like this:

```
curl --location 'https://api-secure-uat.com/v1' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml' \
--header 'SOAPAction: http://secure.com/Services/v1/CreateSession' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer qv5bBU9HuQ0F5p3CT5EXAXbXd3w2' \
--data '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CreateSession xmlns="http://secure.com/Services/v1/">
<reqCreateSession>
<client>
<name>hrix03hQoSwweIE1NuHrDHu5Ooz66jmx</name>
<clientId>hrix03hQoSwweIE1NuHrDHu5Ooz66jmx</clientId>
<appservername>test-client</appservername>
<appserverip>10.10.10.10</appserverip>
<appservertimestamp>2023-12-26T16:28:59.704Z</appservertimestamp>
<SubClientId xsi:nil="true"/>
<SubClientName xsi:nil="true"/>
<SalesAgentId xsi:nil="true"/>
<SalesAgentName xsi:nil="true"/>
</client>
</CreateSession>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

I am trying this C# code to call the service method:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
         Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
         {
              Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport
         }
    };

// Create an instance of the service client
CoAServicesClient optixServiceclient = new CoAServicesClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(url));
    
// Add Bearer token to the HTTP request headers
HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
requestProperty.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {bearerToken}";

OperationContextScope contextScope = new OperationContextScope(optixServiceclient.InnerChannel);
            
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestProperty;

try
{
    // Calling service method here
    CreateSessionResponse csResponse = optixServiceclient.CreateSessionAsync(GetCreateSessionObject()).Result;

    // Process the result here
    Console.WriteLine($"Service response: {csResponse}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error calling service: {ex.Message}");
}
```

I can see that I am passing the correct headers but still getting 401.

Can anyone guide what could be wrong with code that its not working?

**The best part is, even SOAPUI is throwing same error 401 while only postman seems to be working. Can I get any clue as to what could possibly be wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Try code:

```
CoAServicesClient optixServiceclient=new CoAServicesClient();
var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpRequestProperty.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {bearerToken}";
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
```

Generally speaking, you do not need to write endpoints and bindings with service references.

```
CoAServicesClient optixServiceclient=new CoAServicesClient();
```

If you have other settings in the webservice, it should be said separately.

When calling a service, use:

CreateSessionResponse csResponse = `optixServiceclient.CreateSessionAsync(GetCreateSessionObject()).Result;`

However, this method is generally used by the **WCF**. I think you can try **httpclient** as well.